# Add Colour to KML LAyer on Google maps

Tags: swift, google-maps, kml

How can i add colour to kml Layer.

layer is showing On map but there's colour is Purple for all but in KMl files colour for each KMl layer is mention.
is there any way I can add colour programmatically to KML Layer using swift

any help regarding to this will be appreciated .

thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

When you're dealing with KML its basically an XML file and the colors are coded in to the file.  If you want to change the colors, you need to first parse the KML into an XML using something like AEXML.

```
     let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "(your file name)", ofType: "kml")

     guard let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) else {
     print("error loading kml from URL")
     return}


     var options = AEXMLOptions()
     options.parserSettings.shouldProcessNamespaces = true
     options.parserSettings.shouldReportNamespacePrefixes = true
     var kml = try AEXMLDocument(xml: data, options: options)
```

now you have an XML file that you can edit simply using

```
     kml.replacingOccurrences(of: "ff000000", with: "ff8f8f8f")
```

where you substitute the "of" and "with" with the colors you're looking for and want to replace with.

Bonus tip:
You can use the same .replacingOccurrences method to change the line width in the kml too.

EDIT:
Once you make your edits, convert the xml into data and pass it to the Google Maps kml renderer.

```
     guard let kmlData = kml.data(using: .utf8) else {return}
     kmlParser = GMUKMLParser(data: kmlData)
     kmlParser.parse()



     renderer = GMUGeometryRenderer(map: mapView,
                                    geometries: kmlParser.placemarks,
                                    styles: kmlParser.styles)

     renderer.render()
```

If you need help understanding the structure of the kml better, just change the extension to xml and load it up in your browser or some other xml reader